# MC34063 24VDC to 5VDC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, mc34063

I am trying to set up a 24VDC => 5VDC converter using the MC34063.

The schematic is as follows:

[image: Schematic]

I used the following component values:

- C1 = 100µF
- C2 = C3 =150µF
- C4 = 100nF
- C5 = 0.47nF
- L1 = 150µH
- R1 = 0.33R
- R2 = 3.6K
- R3 = 1.2K
- D1 = 1N5819

The 5V output is unstable, it oscillates between 4.9V and 5.6V.

[image]

I tried several values of coil going from 100µH to 220µH, of capacitor up to 470µF.  Nothing I've tried makes a clean 5V.

Do you have any idea where the problem can come from?

Comment: What does the output voltage look like with a light load or a full load? This time try and show a horizontal picture with better focus and try and capture the full scope screen.

Comment: Can you please provide a picture of your hardware? The circuit diagram looks good, but 34063 are sensitive to improper ground paths

Comment: Are you sure C5 is 470pF and not, say, 470nF?

Comment: @Andyaka I put no load on the output, I will make a better quality photo

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes C5 it's 0.47µF

Comment: @Jens For the moment I am on a prototype plate to validate the assembly and start the manufacturing of the PCB

Comment: This is your comment: `yes C5 it's 0.47µF` And this is from question body: `With as component values: C1 = 100µF C2 = C3 =150µF C4 = 100nF C5 = 0.47nF L1 = 150µH R1 = 0.33R R2 = 3.6K R3 = 1.2K D1 = 1N5819`. Which C5 is the correct value?

Answer (score 2):

If C5 is 0.47uF as mentioned in a comment, and not 470pF, you will get a very slow oscillation frequency and you would need a huge (1000x bigger) inductor to get a steady output. Looks like that's your problem.

Comment: It's indicated as 0.47n in the question body but the OP says it's 470n.

Comment: @RohatKılıç yes but i'm an idiot ... I reversed the capacitors during the assembly, I put the right value this time and it works like a charm ....

SpehroPefhany Thank you very much for your help, I could have gone around in circles for a long time for an error of inattention....

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with this chip in a really bad layout. If a minimum load does not help, try to lower the frequency with 680 pF as C5.

In my case a capacitor of 100 pF between pin 5 (CII) and GND finally worked. This is a very unwished solution because the feedback response is downgraded, but the erratic coupling of switching nodes was suppressed. This is not a classical solution, more a compensation of another problem.